# How to prepopulate data from database to a django form

Tags: html, django

I am trying to prepopulate the values from my database into the django form. I tried to pass the object instance from model.py but I wasn't able to render the value. Is there a better way to render it?

Here is my code:

**view.py**

```
class myview(TemplateView):
    def get(self,request):
        userinfo = UserInfo.object.get(id=1)
        form = UserForm(form)
        return render(request,'user.html',{'form':form})
```

**template.html**

```
{{form.username}}
{{form.address}}
```

It throws the error :

> User object has no attribute 'get'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by passing the object with keyword instance

view.py

```
class myview(TemplateView):
 def get(self,request):
  userinfo = UserInfo.object.get(id=1)
  form = UserForm(instance=userinfo)
  return render(request,'user.html',{'form':form})
```